# Connecting Nintendo Switches over Site-to-Site VPN

Tags: openvpn, pfsense, multicast, igmp, opnsense

I have two sites connected with an OpenVPN tunnel on which I am trying to get two Nintendo Switch devices (one at each site) to see eachother so that they can game as if they're on the same LAN. All TCP / UDP traffic between the two devices is allowed and flowing correctly, so I believe the issue is unrouted multicast traffic. I suspect that I need to somehow create a virtual IP on each network with a 1:1 NAT that forwards traffic to the device on the other network but none of the combinations I've tried have worked so far. One site is running OPNSense on its edge firewall, the other PFSense, fully updated.

Comment: Multicasts are on specific IPs so I dont think its a NAT your after -  A layer 2 tunnel should work (GRE ) - I would of thought some IGMP setup may also work - but I've only done that acrross routers within a LAN on Cisco devices.

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/spacemeowx2/switch-lan-play  If traffic works over the site to site vpn, then you can point both the switches at this server

Comment: Thanks, my problem is apparently dumber than all that. Nintendo products use some kind of wifi-direct or bluetooth connection when they say they're using a "Local Connection" apparently, at least according to my brother whose more familiar with Nintendo stuff than I am. With just converting my layer 3 TUN connection to a layer 2 TAP connection and adding IGMP and MDNS repeating / proxying to both firewalls I can see all the cast devices on the other side and cast to those devices, so this was bound to fail. Might be possible with a wired connection, but I don't care enough to buy an adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever it's worth, the problem I thought I was solving, IGMP/mDNS traffic not crossing the VPN was solved by converting my OpenVPN TUN (Layer 3) connection to a TAP (Layer 2) connection and adding IGMP and mDNS proxy services to both firewalls to push the traffic. I later found out that the switch was not using the LAN at all and was using Nintendo's proprietary "Local Connection" (read Bluetooth) to host rooms for Mario Party so cross site play was not possible. As a plus(?) I can now see all the chromecasts on the other network from here.